# Как лучше писать контроллеры анимаций?

Tags: c#, unity3d

AnimationsController:

```
interface IAnimController
{
    public void ChoseAnimation(AnimationsController animation);
    public void PlayAnimation(List<object> someArgs);
    public void ChoseAnimator(Animator animator);
}

public abstract class AnimationsController : MonoBehaviour, IAnimController
{
    public virtual void ChoseAnimation(AnimationsController animation) { }

    public virtual void PlayAnimation(List<object> someArgs) { }
    
    public virtual void ChoseAnimator(Animator animator) { }
}
```

PlayerAnimationsController:

```
public class PlayerAnimationsController : AnimationsController
    {
        protected static Animator _animator;
        
        private PlayerAnimationsController _animation;
        
        public sealed override void ChoseAnimation(AnimationsController animation)
        {
            _animation = (PlayerAnimationsController)animation;
        }

        public sealed override void ChoseAnimator(Animator animator)
        {
            _animator = animator;
        }

        public override void PlayAnimation(List<object> someArgs)
        {
            _animation.PlayAnimation(someArgs);
        }
    }

    public sealed class WalkAnimation : PlayerAnimationsController
    {
        public override void PlayAnimation(List<object> someArgs)
        {
            // проигрывание анимации ходьбы
        }
    }

    public sealed class JumpAnimation : PlayerAnimationsController
    {
        public override void PlayAnimation(List<object> someArgs)
        {
            // проигрывание анимации прыжка
        }
    }

    public sealed class RunAnimation : PlayerAnimationsController
    {
        public override void PlayAnimation(List<object> someArgs)
        {
            // проигрывание анимации бега
        }
    }
```

PlayerMovement:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _animator;
    private PlayerAnimationsController _playerAnimations;

    private void Start()
    {
        _playerAnimations.ChoseAnimator(_animator);
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 direction)
    {
        _playerAnimations.ChoseAnimation(new WalkAnimation());
        _playerAnimations.PlayAnimation(new List<object> { direction.x, direction.z });
    }
}
```

Через метод выбора анимации(ChoseAnimation) я пытался записать ссылку на класс, анимацию которого мне нужно проиграть(_playerAnimations.ChoseAnimation(new WalkAnimation())), но Unity не приветствует создание объекта класса, который наследуется от MonoBehaviour, поэтому я посчитал такой способ "костылём". Помогите, пожалуйста, переписать этот код(или навести на мысль, как лучше сделать), а то, я что-то не могу представить этот код по другому.

Comment: mecanim имеет продвинутый механизм переключения анимациий в зависимости от состояния.

Comment: @ValeraKvip, я его и применяю

Comment: А вы вообще хоть приблизительно понимаете как работает `Animator`? Его граф переходов?

Comment: @Yaroslav, нет.